# Solving a Word Maze Using Recusion (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, maze

So, I'm very **very** new to Java, and I've been working on this problem for some time now. It's for a school project (which has been overdue for about 2 weeks) and I was looking for hints or some possible solutions that could guide me from this point.

The object of this program is to take in a .txt file (something like this: https://pastebin.com/hvg0P2Pe) and go through a 2D grid of letters in order to find provided words; the words can be connected horizontally, vertically, and diagonally. The catch for this program is that it cannot be done using iteration, it has to be done recursively.

Here's the output for the following code: https://pastebin.com/uXiDHjvU

I'm not completely sure what is the issue with my program; I've been scratching my head for days. Any support would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class wordMaze1 {

    private static boolean wordCheck;

    public static boolean wordSearch(char[][] letter, String words, int r, int c) {

        if (letter[r][c] != words.charAt(0))
            return false;
        if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(c))
            return true;
        if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r, c - 1);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r, c + 1);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r - 1, c);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r + 1, c);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r - 1, c - 1);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r + 1, c - 1);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r - 1, c + 1);
        } else if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(0)) {
            letter.toString().toLowerCase();
            return wordSearch(letter, words.substring(1), r + 1, c + 1);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
            int numGrids = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            for (int i = 1; i < numGrids + 1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Grid #" + i + ":");
                int size = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                char[][] grid = new char[size][size];
                String[] tempGrid = new String[size];
                for (int t = 0; t < size; t++) {
                    tempGrid[t] = scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(tempGrid[t]);
                }
                int wordNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                String[] words = new String[wordNum];
                for (int w = 0; w < wordNum; w++) {
                    words[w] = scan.nextLine();

                    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
                            grid[r][c] = tempGrid[r].charAt(c);
                            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
                            if (grid[r][c] == words[w].charAt(0))
                                if (wordSearch(grid, words[w], r, c)) {
                                    wordCheck = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                        //System.out.print(grid);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    if (wordCheck == true)
                        System.out.println(words[w] + " is found.");
                    else
                        System.out.println(words[w] + " is NOT found.");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causes exception:

```
if (letter[r][c] == words.charAt(c))
```

If you replace charAt(c) with charAt(0), it should work better

Comment: This line is a base case for when the last letter is found; if you look below that line is there. I don't know how to identify what letter is the last so I put c there.